# validates_uniqueness_of

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

What I am trying to do is to come up with the model for `Project`, where only one project could be active at a time. So I am thinking to create  one table for `projects` and another one for `status`.

How can I make sure that only one project is active at a given time ? I looked into `validates_uniqueness_of`  but I am little confused if thats the solution for me, because I do want to able to override the current status, despite the fact if one project is already enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Project` should have something like an `:active` attribute. You can then add validation like this on your `Project` model

```
validate :ensure_only_one_active_project

def ensure_only_one_active_project
  active_project = Project.where(active: true).first

  errors.add(:active, "Another project is already active. Only one project can be active at a time") unless active_project.nil? || active_project.id == self.id
end
```

Now, if a `Project` already is active, and have another *(currently inactive)* `Project` `@project`, and try to do

```
@project.active = true
@project.valid? # this will return false
```

`@project.errors` will contain a Hash with `:active` attribute having the above error since

- 1 `Project` is already active
- The active project is **not** the current `Project` we're saving.

Comment: Thanks! This makes perfect sense

Comment: Hi @Deefour, May i knw why is Project.where(active: true).first?  what does .first indicate? Can just Project.where('active' => true) instead? *passed by*

Comment: `where(...)` returns an Array to `active_project`. I want only the first in the set to do my comparison agains `self.id`. `first` is documented **[here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-first)**.